# Citrus flightbooking sample execution?

Tags: testing, citrus-framework

I am new to Citrus so I tried to execute

flight booking sample but I face some problems. First of all, I think that something

is wrong with the readme file (readme.md on https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/tree/master/sample-flightbooking) . "Got to the folder and start the BookStore WebService application in a Web Container. The easiest way for you to do this is to execute" it seems to be part of another sample readme file.

When I execute `mvn jetty:run` , jetty server starts but I got these messages :

> - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=4, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL:
>   tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused: connect 11:18:22,197 ERROR ageListenerContainer| Could not
>   refresh JMS Connection for destination 'Travel.Agency.Request.Queue'

Also, when I try `mvn integration-test` (while jetty server runs) , tests fails and got these messages :

> [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time
> elapsed: 4.575 s <<< FAILURE! - in
> com.consol.citrus.samples.flightbooking.FlightBookingIT [ERROR]
> FlightBookingIT(com.consol.citrus.samples.flightbooking.FlightBookingIT)
> Time elapsed: 1.514 s  <<< FAILURE!
> com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: Test case failed
> Caused by: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException:
> Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested
> exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL:
> tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
> refused: connect Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect
> to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect Caused by:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

It seems like something is missing (JMS broker, I suppose?) on localhost:61616 .

Could you please guide me how to execute successfully the sample?

(I am running Windows 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Answer

I am sorry for your bad first impression with Citrus. You are right about the README file, this seems to be a copy-paste error. If will fix it in the repo.

The correct maven command to execute is:

```
mvn clean verify -Dembedded
```

## Long Answer

The `embedded` parameter will activate two profiles in the POM, `activemq-embedded` and `jetty-embedded`. As their names suggest this will start an in-memory ActiveMQ broker, and a Jetty server with the system under test deployed before the integration tests run.

Note that in other samples, e.g. `sample-databind`, the README suggests running `mvn clean install -Dembedded=true`. This will do almost the same, but I prefer the `verify` lifecycle since it doesn't copy the artefacts to the local maven repository. Moreover, the `=true` part for profile activation is not necessary, since the corresponding profiles are activated as soon as the property exists (irrelevant of its actual value), see

```xml
<activation>
  <property>
    <name>embedded</name>
  </property>
</activation>
```

Comment: I have just updated the `sample-flightbooking` repository's README, see [GitHub repo](https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/tree/master/sample-flightbooking).

Comment: You could also run the activemq message broker in a separate command line terminal `mvn activemq:run`